# Как лучше спроектировать БД? Для теста

Tags: mysql, vue3

Есть тест (ответ на вопросы) выводиться вопрос и к нему варианты ответа. После выбора ответа нажимается кнопка проверить и выводиться alert с ответом правильно/не правильно и выводиться следующий вопрос. На json это работает отлично) Но нужно перенести на БД (mysql).

запросы через api (express) но думаю это не так важно)

json:

```
 questions: [
        {
          id: '1',
          question: 'Вопрос 1',
          answers: ['Ответ 1', 'Ответ 2', 'Ответ 3', 'Ответ 4'],
          correct: 'Ответ 1'
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          question: 'Вопрос 2',
          answers: ['Ответ 1', 'Ответ 2', 'Ответ 3'],
          correct: 'Ответ 3'
        },
        {
          id: '3',
          question: 'Вопрос 2',
          answers: ['Ответ 1', 'Ответ 2', 'Ответ 3', 'Ответ 4', 'Ответ 5'],
          correct: 'Ответ 4'
        }
      ]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше хранить вопросы и ответы к ним в бд, и как их дергать за один - два запроса, а не при каждом ответе на предыдущий вопрос тянуть следующий с ответами из бд

Comment: Что значит не тянуть следующий при ответе на предыдущий ? А в как вы это себе по другому предполагаете. Сразу отдавать на клиента через api все вопросы со всеми ответами ? Но тогда на клиенте можно будет подсмотреть правильные ответы сразу как их api вернет и ответить верно на все. Правильный ответ на клиента должен приходить по api только после того, как человек уже ответил и вместе с ним следующий вопрос

Comment: А сруктура БД зависит от того что именно вы ходите хранить. Если только показанный json, я бы предложил вообще одну таблицу, с вопросами и в ней поле в виде json массива ответов. Но ведь вы наверное потом в БД захотите хранить пользователей и то как они ответили, а если так то структура должна быть совершенно иной. Не зная задачи полностью, со всей информацией какую вообще информацию храним, где и в каком виде используем (т.е. что потом накопленной инфой делать, может какие статистические формы по ней понадобятся), невозможно спроектировать правильно

Comment: @Mike На данный момент задача заключается лишь в том что бы отправлять пользователю вопрос и проверять ответ. Фитбэка никакого не планируется. Проверка ответа осуществляется на стороне клиента на основе значения correct и выбраного юзером ответа. Остановлюсь пожалуйста пока на json. Спасибо

Comment: @Mike подскажите, пожалуйста, получаю в ответ из БД json в [ ]. Как его парситть если при выборе: questions["data"][0] получаю ошибку

`[ { "id": "1", "answers": [ "Ответ 1", "Ответ 2", "Ответ 3", "Ответ 4" ], "correct": "Ответ 1", "question": "Вопрос 1" }, { "id": "2", "answers": [ "Ответ 1", "Ответ 2", "Ответ 3" ], "correct": "Ответ 3", "question": "Вопрос 2" }, { "id": "3", "answers": [ "Ответ 1", "Ответ 2", "Ответ 3", "Ответ 4", "Ответ 5" ], "correct": "Ответ 4", "question": "Вопрос 2" } ]`

Comment: так вы его небось в виде текста получаете, а не в виде массива. Надо его перевести в нормальный массив/объект. т.е. использовать что то вроде JSON.Parse (если вы на js пишите)

Comment: @Mike Сори могу тупить) Если вывожу через: `{{ JSON.parse(this.questions["data"]) }}` Получую: 
`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` Но если выводить просто: `this.questions["data"]` то `[ { "id": "1", "answers": [ "Ответ 1", "Ответ 2", "Ответ 3", "Ответ 4" ], "correct": "Ответ 1", "question": "Вопрос 1" }, { "id": "2", "answers": ....`